# Send Matic on Polygon (Python Script)

Tags: polygon

I just wanted to know how I can adapt this code from sending eth to sending MATIC on the Polygon Network. Thanks for the help.....Cheers

````
import os


#Get the hgtps endpoint for the polygon network and create web3 object
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider
         ('https://polygon-mainnet.infura.io/v3/5ba943bce7ef47a9bd791767ee5ce3d5'))
 
#Test if it works
#x = w3.isConnected()
#print(x)

# Set up the addresses to send from and to
public_address = ''
receiver_address = ''
priv_key = os.getenv('PRIVATE_KEY')

# Convert to checksumadress (not to loose bites when sending)
sender1 = Web3.toChecksumAddress(public_address)
receiver1  =  Web3.toChecksumAddress(receiver_address)

# Set up the nonce
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(sender1)

# Set up the transaction
tx = {'nonce': nonce,
      'to': receiver1,
      'value' w3.toWei(1, eth),
      'gas': 21000,
      'gasPrice': w3.toWei(50, gwei)
      }

signed_tx = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, priv_key)

tx_hash = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
print(web3.toHex(tx_hash)) ```
````

Comment: This script won't work because MATIC on the Polygon network is ERC20 token, the script transfers the native currencty. Search for a script to transfer ERC20 tokens.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of chainId is 1 for ETH, You must add the correct value of chainId for POLYGON.
more information: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-155

```
tx = {'nonce': nonce,
      'to': receiver1,
      'value' w3.toWei(1, eth),
      'gas': 21000,
      'gasPrice': w3.toWei(50, gwei),
      'chainId': 137
      }
```